# javascript only work in 1 data

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I'm trying to get button hidden using javascript.
here the javascript code:

```html
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("view1");
    var a="<?php echo $data[0]->status==1;?>";
    if(!a==0){
        btn.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
<script>
    var btn = document.getElementById("view2");
    var a="<?php echo $data[0]->status;?>";
    if(!a==0){
        btn.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

[image]

but actually only 1 data javascript worked

Comment: what does the code look like in the BROWSER (use developer tools) - are there any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: `a` will be either "true" or "false" (the strings, not the booleans) so, your logic looks inelegant

Comment: no error in developer tools,can you give me elegant code or great solution

Comment: so - what does the code look like in the BROWSER

Comment: <pre><span class="label label-sm label-info "> 
             Waiting</span> <code>

Comment: so - what does the **code you posted, i.e. the JAVASCRIPT BLOCKS,** look like in the **BROWSER**

Comment: <a href=""  type="button" id="view2" class="btn btn-circle blue btn-sm" style="display: none;">View</a>

Comment: last attempt ... so - what does the **javascript code you posted**, i.e. the **JAVASCRIPT BLOCKS**, look like **in the BROWSER**

Comment: in the browser, you **will not see the PHP stuff** you will see the **result of the PHP stuff** ... I want to see what that looks like

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID in one HTML document. IDs (identifiers) are supposed to be unique. Look into `name` or `class` and selecting multiple elements using `document.getElementsByName` or `document.getElementsByClassName`.
Alternatively, if your HTML is generated from PHP as well, display / hide the buttons in the HTML directly.

Comment: i'm newbie,can you give me example with name or class please.